# Use of Progress Bar in C#.net

Tags: c#

In one of my winform I am trying to Populate data of employees days present days and absent days on a datagrid according to month and year select on combo box.

Once click on 'SHOW' button it takes sometime to populate, so I want to use progress bar at the bottom bar stating "List is being Populated"(like in Add or remove program in control panel).
If theirs any other suggestions to make it work is most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I don't find a question here. So you want a progress bar, thats good, so how is it going?

Comment: What is taking time to get the data to populate? Is it the database scripts that calculate the data? You should probably look to improve the performance of that query rather than worry about displaying the progress bar

Comment: while the list is populating it should show progress bar , progressing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

You should also search before you ask questions, [there are lots of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+backgroundworker+progressbar&submit=search) on here that you could look at which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BackgroundWorker thread to handle data population.  This will give the user visual feedback while keeping the UI responsive.  Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ProgressBar to a panel on your .NET StatusBar control by subclassing the StatusBar. Then you use the derived StatusBar on your WinForm just as you would use the standard control. [See Example and article](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/ProgressStatus.aspx)

You can try this [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10166/C-StatusBarProgressPanel-Control) too, sample code is offered to download.